# В классе нет метода

Tags: java

Не могу добавить элемент в `arraylist`, пишет:

```
Cannot resolve method 'add' in 'ArrayList'
```

что делать?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Zaur");
        list.add("Ivan");
        list.add("Mariya");
        list.add("Kolya");
        list.add("Elena");
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте ту ли библиотеку вы импортируете  `java.util.ArrayList;` или же есть еще какая библиотека `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

в самый вверх под **package**

Answer (score 0):

Настроить jdk в проекте. Код работает: [https://ideone.com/4YjwOa](https://ide%6Fne.com/4YjwOa).